# Powershell -Filter not working as expected

Tags: powershell

The following filter is to make sure only .properties files are inspected however other files such as .sh are being inspected. Can anyone see a mistake in my filter?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryToTarget -Filter "*.properties" -Recurse | where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | % {
```

Thank you!

Comment: Having some samples of the result of your command would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want -Include:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryToTarget -Include *.properties -Recurse | where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | % {
```